# download zip file php

Tags: php, apache, download, zip

So I have been attempting to create and Download a .zip file from my WAMP server to be used on a private development server I am working on, and seem to have hit some major issues when trying to download the .zip file I have created.

The code appears to work as intended. It looks through a folder which contains the files I want downloaded, and adds them to an array to be used by my zipper class (function calls near the bottom).

When I run this code the .zip file is created on the server; I can see that it is there, open it, see that the files were added to the .zip. As well i can drag the zipped folder off of my local wamp server and extract it from my client machine fine. 
The problem is when I try and download the compressed file. It appears to download the file, but when I go to open it a Windows box appears saying "Windows cannot open the folder, The Compressed (zipped) folder /path&name/ is invalid", yet it works fine on the server end.

I have attempted using this scheme to download and view single files as well (Non zipped) and they always come out as random text, which leads me to believe that it has something to do with serving the download from the server to the client machine.

As well I have attempted to run this code on my live server. Same thing happens, when trying to view, except that (in chrome) a message saying "/filename/ is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous".

I have checked various posting on stackoverflow for a solution and non seem to help.

```
<?php

require_once 'zipper.php';
$dir_path = "files/";

$arrFiles = array(); //Array Of files to be compressed into zip

if(is_dir($dir_path)){
    $files = scandir($dir_path); //create and array that stores all dir files.directories including '.' and '..'
    foreach($files as $newFile){ //Loop through the files
        if($newFile != '.' && $newFile != '..'){ //If the current found is NOT . or ..
            echo "$newFile<br>";
            $newFile = $dir_path . $newFile; 
            $arrFiles[] = $newFile; //add to the array of files to compress/zip
        }
    }
}

//print_r($dir_path."name.zip");

$zipper = new Zipper; //create the zipper object (contains functions for preparing the .ZIP)
$zipper->add($arrFiles); //add files to Zipper ZIP array

$filename = "myFile.zip";
$filepath = $dir_path.$filename; //Path to the new .zip with the ZIP name included in the path
echo $filepath;
echo "<br>";

$zipper->store($filepath); //create the ZIP & store for download

header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename=".basename($filepath).";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath));
    readfile("$filepath");
?>
```

Below is the "zipper.php" file that I used.

```
<?php
class Zipper{
private $_files = array(), $_zip;

public function __construct(){
    $this->_zip = new ZipArchive;
}

public function add($input){
    if(is_array($input)){
        $this->_files = array_merge($this->_files, $input);
    }else{
        $this->_files[] = $input;
    }
}

public function store($location = null){ //used for storing the files added from the directory
    if(count($this->_files) && $location){
        foreach($this->_files as $index => $file){
            if(!file_exists($file)){
                unset($this->_files[$index]);
            }
            elseif(preg_match('/.zip$/', $file)){ //if the file was already compressed once, remove it from the array of files to zip
                unset($this->_files[$index]);
            }
        }
        print_r($this->_files);
        if($this->_zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)){ //create the .ZIP; if it exists overwrite, else create it

            foreach($this->_files as $file){
                $this->_zip->addFile($file, $file); //for each file in our array add it to the zip
            }

            $this->_zip->close(); //close the zip once completed
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$dir_path = "files/";

$arrFiles = array(); //Array Of files to be compressed into zip

if (is_dir($dir_path)) {
    $files = scandir($dir_path); //create and array that stores all dir files.directories including '.' and '..'
    foreach ($files as $newFile) { //Loop through the files
        if ($newFile != '.'&&$newFile != '..') { //If the current found is NOT . or ..
//            echo "$newFile<br>";
            $newFile = $dir_path . $newFile;
            $arrFiles[] = $newFile; //add to the array of files to compress/zip
        }
    }
}

//print_r($dir_path."name.zip");

$zipper = new Zipper; //create the zipper object (contains functions for preparing the .ZIP)
$zipper->add($arrFiles); //add files to Zipper ZIP array

$filename = "myFile.zip";
$filepath = $dir_path . $filename; //Path to the new .zip with the ZIP name included in the path
//echo $filepath;
//echo "<br>";

$zipper->store($filepath); //create the ZIP & store for download

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($filepath) . ";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));
readfile("$filepath");

class Zipper
{
    private $_files = array(), $_zip;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_zip = new ZipArchive;
    }

    public function add($input)
    {
        if (is_array($input)) {
            $this->_files = array_merge($this->_files, $input);
        } else {
            $this->_files[] = $input;
        }
    }

    public function store($location = null)
    { //used for storing the files added from the directory
        if (count($this->_files)&&$location) {
            foreach ($this->_files as $index => $file) {
                if (!file_exists($file)) {
                    unset($this->_files[$index]);
                } elseif (preg_match('/.zip$/', $file)) { //if the file was already compressed once, remove it from the array of files to zip
                    unset($this->_files[$index]);
                }
            }
//            print_r($this->_files);
            if ($this->_zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) { //create the .ZIP; if it exists overwrite, else create it

                foreach ($this->_files as $file) {
                    $this->_zip->addFile($file, $file); //for each file in our array add it to the zip
                }

                $this->_zip->close(); //close the zip once completed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really strange, I commented out the headers that you did in yours and even still its not working. Are you possibly running yours on a wamp/lamp server as well? I am wondering if its something wrong with my php configuration.

Comment: I tested on wamp, i did put Content-Disposition back into one line. With my first attempt it was downloading an attachment with the same name as the php file

Comment: I have had it download the "download.php" file as well before. For me it does download the "myFile.zip" It just cant be opened for what ever reason. Leaving the headers that you left up still ends me with a zip file that cant be opened. odd question, but did you make a folder called "files" and populate it with a few different files?

Comment: it wasn't called "files", but i did make a folder and put some files in it. If the zip file is 0 length u will get an error like what you describe.

Comment: Thats really strange. Its definitely not having to do with the zip file size, i put some rather large files in there and it still downloaded, but failed to open. Ive tested the program on 2 different windows machines as well (both running windows 10) and neither of them can open the file either. Is it possibly something to do with the browser? I personally wouldnt think so.

Comment: Is there any output being sent before the readfile, eg a warning notice etc, Open the zip file you get downloaded in a hexeditor and see what the first few chars are, and compare that to the orginal

Comment: I opened it with a hexeditor and it comes up with a bunch of random characters. How ever the start of the file appears to be an output of the echo statements that I had throughout the php program. I tested the zip functionality out by putting in a file that was 4(ish)mb and downloaded it, the download came out around that size, yet is not usable. So i would believe it has something to do with the header serving the download over in a strange encrypted format

Comment: If you comment out the readfile(), then does it download a 0 length zip file?

Comment: Yes the size is 0 when i remove the readfile() function call. And if i remove the header(content-type: application/zip) it downloads the file as "download.php" with content being unreadable

Comment: what does this line in the zipper class do?             print_r($this->_files);

Comment: I opened the zip file ok and it listed the files (using winrar), but i didn't actually try to open any of the content files. Once i did that it failed. I commented out the print_r and the 3 echo statements as they are being concatenated into the file

Comment: Just prints out the current $_files array to the page so i can make sure that it is compressing/adding all the files to the zip. Im not sure why it is concatenating the output of those print statements to the files.... there really doesnt seem to be anywhere obvious that it would do that

Comment: So i just ran a quick test, i commented out all the code that actually compresses the files and compressed it instead using 7-zip with the same name that my headers look for, and it downloaded. I am wondering if it has something to do with the .zip not closing properly at the end of the procedure.

Comment: Did u comment out all the echos and prints and it is still not working? Can u post the zip file (that is downloaded from the script) somewhere so i can have a look at it

Comment: Just removed all the echos and prints and that seemed to work. I have no idea why but it appears to be that they were somehow getting adding onto the file that was in fact the ZIP making it a giant mess of data/text. Now I just need to get it working on my server. Thanks for spending the time to help out here.

Comment: I suspect there is possibility problem with the server setting (such as apache): try to download directly by typing the full address in the browser instead of using PHP. If the problem persists, it means the problem is not in the PHP but in the server setting.